# How to stop automatically audio playing when we receive a call or play a video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I build flutter app with local assets audio playing. How to stop automatically audio playing (streaming) when we receive a call or play a video? I used audioplayers 0.7.8 to build application.

pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.7.8

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```